# When I click anywhere in my excel doc, while exporting data to that doc, it will throw: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472

Tags: c#, excel, exception

So my code is making an excel document and loading some lists in different sheets. Now, whenever I click on a random cell it will stop loading the data and give me this expection: `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472` in my Visual Studio. Now, when I press `start debugging(f5)` again it will finish the excel doc and filling in the rest of the data. How can I possibly fix this?

```
excelDataHandler.excel_create("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\testmap\\testno3.xlsx");
for (int i = 0; i < ListOfLists.Count; i++)
{
     for (int j = 1; j <= ListOfLists[i].Count; j++)
     {
          excelDataHandler.excel_setValue("B" + j, ListOfLists[i][j-1], (i+1));
     }
}
excelDataHandler.excel_close("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\testmap\\testno3.xlsx");
```

ExcelDataHandler:

```
    private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass appExcel;
    private static Workbook newWorkbook_First = null;
    private static _Worksheet objsheet = null;
    private static _Worksheet newSheets = null;    '

public void excel_create(String path)
        {

            try
            {
                appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
                appExcel.Visible = true;
                newWorkbook_First = appExcel.Workbooks.Add(1);
                newSheets = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)newWorkbook_First.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 30, Type.Missing);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("Error");
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }

public void excel_setValue(string cellname, string value, int workSheet)
        {
            //error in this line below
  ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)newWorkbook_First.Sheets[workSheet]).get_Range(cellname).set_Value(Type.Missing, value);
        }

public void excel_close(string save)
        {
            if (save == "")
            {
            }
            else
            {
                newWorkbook_First.SaveAs(save);
            }
            if (appExcel != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    newWorkbook_First.Close();
                 //   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet);
                //    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel.ActiveWorkbook);
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel);
                    appExcel = null;
                    objsheet = null;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    appExcel = null;
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried this: `(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)newWorkbook_First.Sheets[workSheet] = (_Worksheet)appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;` but it gave an error

Comment: This is a common cross-threading issue, Excel isn't a multi-threaded application, and the error you are getting is indicating that you are trying to make an object model call while the property browser is suspended (probably due to the UI change).

Comment: @Claies How do I program it, so that it will continue with its process and ignoring the error? or isnt this possible?

Comment: you don't have enough of the code around your `excelDataHandler` here to know for sure where it's deadlocking, but generally, that's an error that you just have to catch, swallow, and retry your change.

Comment: @Claies Can I do this with a try/catch finally? I also edited the questoin, this is pretty much all code u need i guess

Comment: @Claies I changed the code to this: `try
                    {
                        excelDataHandler.excel_setValue("B" + j, siemensLijsten[i][j - 1], "", (i + 2));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }` But it still gives the error  @ `throw;`

Comment: right, you have to evaluate `e` to see if it is the exception, and if so, then retry.  using `throw` just says you know you got an exception but you don't want to handle it, let someone else deal with it, which it's not, when you get "Unhandled Exception".

Comment: bear in mind, if you just swallow the exception and continue, you aren't "retrying" the line in the loop that caused the error; you will definitely need some robust checking to ensure that you aren't missing lines of data in your output.

Comment: @Claies Indeed I see, gonna fix that, doenst have to be that difficult. I got it fixed now by making the loop count 1 down. Is this a good option to fix it? Or are there better ones?

Answer (score 0):

I did put it in a try/catch. And swallowed the exception. This idea was provided by @Claies